# resampling raises ValueError: Values falls before first bin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

I don't understand when and why this error is raised.

From my understanding, `resample` should create as many bins as needed in order to bin all the timestamps of the index. So the message "Values falls before first bin" does not make much sense to me.

Example/actual output:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2021-04-22 01:00:00', end='2021-04-28 01:00', freq='1d'), data = [1]*7)
>>> df 
                     0
2021-04-22 01:00:00  1
2021-04-23 01:00:00  1
2021-04-24 01:00:00  1
2021-04-25 01:00:00  1
2021-04-26 01:00:00  1
2021-04-27 01:00:00  1
2021-04-28 01:00:00  1
>>> df.resample(rule='7d', origin='2021-04-29 00:00:00', closed='right', label='right').sum()
[...]
ValueError: Values falls before first bin
```

Expected output:

```
>>> df.resample(rule='7d', origin='2021-04-29 00:00:00', closed='right', label='right').sum() 
            0
2021-04-29  7 # bin (2021-04-22 00:00:00, 2021-04-29 00:00:00]
```

I'm using `pandas` 1.3.5

Comment: Just to add information: possible related [issue on github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44957)

Answer (score 1):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70436514/timestamp-binning-mechanics-when-resampling) I learned that the timestamps are likely truncated with respect to the unit given in the `rule` argument *before* they are sorted into the correct bin.

This means that

1. `2021-04-22 01:00:00` is rounded to `2021-04-22 00:00:00`
2. `2021-04-22 00:00:00` does not fit into the bin `(2021-04-22 00:00:00, 2021-04-29 00:00:00]` which leads to the `ValueError`

To my eyes this looks like a bug or misfeature. At least one of "truncate timestamps before binning" or "don't add bins as needed, instead raise error" seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found `time = time.dt.normalize()` to help